# Zero Hidden layers + ReLu-Activation + Gradient Descent = Tobit?

Tags: neural-networks, linear-model, tobit-regression

when I train a neural network with zero hidden neurons and ReLu activation functions using gradient descent, can it be expected that the resulting weights are approximatly equal to those of a tobit model where the dependent variable is only to be allowed zero or greater than zero?

Thanks!